# Vuetify 3 schema to form library suggestions needed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

vuetify-jsonschema-form builds forms from JSON schemas.

It is exactly the functionality I need but NOT compatible with Vuetify 3.

I can't seem to locate a comparable library.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be grateful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. VJSF looks great but is also Vuetify 2.

Comment: Just found FormKit which is compatible with Vue 3. I'm okay with settling for a non-vuetify solution.